# Add items in array per a condition

Tags: ruby

```
my_array=[6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 0, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 0, 10, 0, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

If the value is 10 then I should grab the **next two values after the number following 10** and add those value to ten. I'm having trouble doing that.

For the last '10': the value should total 15.

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned? An array of integers?

Comment: for now,yes I am.

Comment: Isn't the last `10` followed by `0` then `3`, whose sum is `13`, not `15`? What if the array ends `..., 10,1]` or `..., 10]`?

Comment: Please submit expected output.

Comment: Isn't the last `10` swallowed up by the previous `10`?

Comment: That's the issue I was facing. Sigh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sum_groups(arr, val, group_size)
  arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i]==val }.map do |i|
    arr[i, group_size].reduce(0) { |t,n| t+n.to_i }
  end
end

my_array=[6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 0, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 0, 10, -1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 10, 5]

sum_groups(my_array, 10, 3)
  #=> [19, 20, 12, 15] 

sum_groups(my_array, 10, 4)
  #=> [19, 19, 17, 15]
```

With Ruby 2.4+ we can use [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) to simplify a bit:

```
def sum_groups(arr, val, group_size)
  arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i]==val }.map do |i|
    arr[i, group_size].sum { |n| n.to_i }
  end
end
```

or replace the antepenultimate line with

```
arr[i, group_size].map(&:to_i).sum
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
[*my_array, 0, 0].each_cons(3).select { |a, b, c| a == 10 }.map(&:sum)
```

This literally does what you describe

- `each_cons(3)` enumerators over all groups of three
- `select` chooses those that start with `10`
- `map(&:sum)` maps them up

And we're padding the array with two zeros for when the array happens to have a 10 near the end. If you don't care about that case leave the padding away.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so I can improve the answer.